# Parse ClassFormDefinition for a Custom Page Type Field's Values

Tags: macros, kentico

I want to populate a dropdown in my webpart from a custom page type field's values.

so for e.g I have a custom pagetype my.pagetype which  has a field called myfield and has value like 1,2,3. How Do I get these 1,2,3 values ?

How do I access through SQL or macro so far I have reached till here and this code is giving me a long XML Schema string which has all fields definition and values of   the custom page type.

```
CMSContext.Current.GlobalObjects.Classes["my.pagetype"].ClassFormDefinition
```

How do I get around?

Answer (score 0):

Are you populating the drop down list in that Page Type manually? (e.g. 1, 2, 3)

If you want to reuse the same list of value in multiple places, it's better for you to create a custom table to store those value (e.g. customtable_myListX). Then for the drop down list, you can use the SQL option (SELECT Value, Display FROM customtable_myListX).

Comment: I was thinking about the custom table as well but I was looking to explore if there is any provision in kentico to achive,  that would be so helpful as the  values are already in database and we just need some parsing function .